# socket.io how to get server socket listen address and port

Tags: node.js, web-services, sockets, networking, socket.io

here is my simplified code example on server side, i need to get to which ip (preferably hostname) and port the server socket is listening, given the socket argument on my callback and assuming i don't have accessible io variable here

```
function myCallback(socket, data){
    //how do i get, to which ip or hostname and port the socket argument is listening
}

io.on('connection', function(socket){
     socket.on('event',function(data){
          myCallback(socket,data);
     });
});
```

Comment: Check where you **start** the server :) It's on the server-side, so just find it in the project. Leaving that on the client is very **very** dangerous!

Comment: the reason i need this is the `myCallback` function is on my library, while `io.on(...` and `socket.on(...` callback is on user's side, my library user only pass the `socket` object to my library, and i need to know based on that `socket` object what is the server listening port and the bind address

Comment: Come on man, there are a lot of ways to pass the needed parameters! :) Pass the file and save a reference inside it. Create global singleton object and put it there... Anything!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
function myCallback(socket, data) {
  var address = socket.handshake.address;
  console.log('New connection from ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
}
```

Comment: isn't that for remote endpoint address, i was asking for server side ip address and port